# How do I display the menu automatically without press key

Tags: java, android, eclipse, menu

Im' so confused, I want to create a menu for an android application but for display the horizontal menu, we have to press the menu key of the emulator.
Is there any method to display without any press action ?
thx

N.B : Sorry, I'm not strong in english.

Answer (score 0):

You can open options menu programmatically by calling [openOptionsMenu()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#openOptionsMenu%28%29).

Comment: Where should put this code ? in oncreate ? or in oncreateoptionsmenu ?

Comment: OnCreateOptoionsMenu is called when your option's menu will be created e.g it will be called after you can openOptionsMenu. If you want to show the options menu when your activity is created put it there it otherwise choose the correct place to put it.